# How to override NSWindow?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I need to create a custom window, so I have created a subclass of NSWindow. I overode the constructor and a bunch of other functions.

I need to replace the current window with the window subclass I created. I know it has something to do with Interface Builder but have no idea what to do. How would I do this?

I tried removing the NSWindow from the Inspector, and instead adding my custom window, however this only results in no window showing up during runtime.

I also edited the app's delegate to change NSWindow to my custom window and also changed the delegate's "main" outlet to my custom window.

I am on Mac OSX Snowleopard using Xcode 3.2.6

Comment: It is 2012. And you are using Xcode 3?!

Comment: Yeah, I need Lion for Xcode 4 (or I could pay). Since I don't wanna pay and I hate Lion, I guess Xcode 3 is my only option ;)

Comment: My solution is for Xcode 4. I'm afraid you won't get any detailed answers for Xcode 3... :P (though, it should be similar)

Comment: You can get Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopared. It comes with the iOS5 SDK as well.

Comment: @Abizern Yeah but I am not in the developer's program so I gotta pay if I want it.

Comment: 5 dollars. Is that too much for a tool as beautiful as Xcode?

Comment: @jenox Well, I am just doing this as a hobby and don't see any features in Xcode 4 that would drastically change my experience so there is not point in me going through the whole process of installation in addition to paying.

Comment: It seems odd that you spent so much to get a Mac but you're unwilling to spend 5 dollars on something as complex as an IDE that you'll be spending a lot of time using.

Comment: @Abizern I bought the Mac for other reasons. I don't see the point of spending money on something that is just a side hobby. If I bought the Mac specifically for programming it would make sense to buy a new IDE; but since Xcode 3 is doing everything I need, I'm happy.

Comment: Fair enough - we all make choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to make sure Interface Builder knows about your custom class. To do this, open your xib file and go to "File->Read Class Files…", and choose your header file.

[image]

Then, select the window you want to change and open the inspector. In the last tab of the inspector, under "Class Identity", there is a text field labeled "Class" simply type your class's name here.

[image]

After you do this, your custom class will be used as the class for that window. It will look like a normal window in IB, but will let you use custom outlets and actions, and will use your class when you actually run your project.

Comment: If you aren't showing it programmatically, make sure the "Visible at Launch" option in the Attributes (first) tab is checked. Otherwise, there might be something wrong with your subclass which is preventing it from showing up.

Comment: Thanks, I guess theres a problem with my subclass. I know this isn't related to the question, but can you suggest a way I could possibly track down why a window isn't launching?

Comment: Try calling -makeKeyAndVisible programmatically.

Comment: @Farhad Start commenting out anywhere where you change/override a setting until it starts working. Look at what methods you overrode and see if there are any effects you aren't accounting for.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw Thank You, I found the problem immediately when I tried that :)

Answer (score 0):

1. go to the third tab of the utilities section when your window is selected
2. enter your custom class name under 'Custom Class'

Comment: Where is utilities? Is it in the Inspector?